# How do I contribute to opencv-python?

Tags: python, open-source-gis, opencv

I have an implementation of a computer vision algorithm in python. I would like to contribute this to opencv-python. This is my first time contributing to FOSS. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The opencv project provides detailed instructions:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/How_to_contribute